# How to prevent WP8 Panorama Control temporarly from sliding?

Tags: c#, slider, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

with the WP7 SDK it was possible to use a BlocksPan to prevent a Panorama control from sliding e.g. if you use a horizontal Slider control on it. This does not work anymore with the WP8 sdk. Microsoft says in there guideline: Just do not use a slider on the panorama. But our app (previously designed for wp7) does need it.

Is there any other way for preventing the panorama from sliding? Will our app fail the store verification if we do it regardless to the guidelines?

Please help ;)

best regards,
Chris

Comment: It shouldn't fail certification. Not sure about preventing the scroll though. (will try and investigate)

Comment: I am sorry. It is working with a real slider per default. Our control is a custom one, but has nearly the same function than a slider. I did not believe that this makes a different, but it does.

Comment: Where is the difference between a slider control and a custom one?

Comment: without being able to see what's different with your custom control

Answer (score 0):

Actually is quite simple you should subscribe to the `ManipulationStarted` event of the panorama control

```
    m_Panorama.ManipulationStarted += m_Panorama_ManipulationStarted;


    void m_Panorama_ManipulationStarted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        m_Panorama.IsHitTestVisible = false;           
    }
```

maybe you will need and just one more boolean variable

Comment: I tried this too, but it's not working as expected. The Panorama Control is first executing the swipe before.